# version bump when updating readme for npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I modify my readme for an npm package I maintain, do I need to bump the version in package.json and do another npm publish? or is there another way to update the readme without a version bump.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "need to", this could be two very different questions:

1. [Is it ok to publish readme changes without bumping the version number?]
2. [Is it technically possible to publish changes without incrementing the version]

The accepted answer (updating via `npm publish --force`, i.e. without incrementing any part of the version number) is a good answer to Q2. But I want to address Q1.

Use of `npm publish --force` is discouraged. Instead, authors are encouraged to use [semantic versioning aka semver](http://semver.org/), which prescribes:

> ... version format of X.Y.Z (Major.Minor.Patch). Bug fixes not
>   affecting the API increment the patch version, backwards compatible
>   API additions/changes increment the minor version, and backwards
>   incompatible API changes increment the major version.

So my answer is: 
While there is technically a way to publish changes without a version bump, you shouldn't do that. For minor edits that don't affect the package's API, you should bump the "patch" version, e.g. from 1.2.0 to 1.2.1.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I figured. I should just bump minor for readme changes.

Comment: force is now deprecated

Comment: Fixing typos or adding information to README.md (or documentation) shouldn't elicit a patch bump. None of the code is changed, just the documentation. And the problem persists in that specific version. You can, of course, deprecate the package but that seems like an awfull way to do it. Since publish --force is now deprecated, I guess the only way is to actually bump patch.

Comment: As an opinion on the matter, I think changes to README.md should be allowed by NPM without a patch bump. README.md is a special case file by virtue of the fact that NPM obliges itself to render it on the site for documentation purposes. Therefor it can be considered 'meta' in the way that no other file in a package would be.

Answer (score 2):

`npm publish --force` will overwrite if version number already exists in registry.

https://npmjs.org/doc/publish.html

Answer (score 2):

## The best thing you can do is:

Publish a new minor version:

```
npm publish [@<scope>/]<name>[@<your new minor version>]
```

Please see the discussion in detail here: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/77758351673/no-more-npm-publish-f

---

#### The following is discouraged(!) and should not be your first option

*Be careful when doing this, after you unpublish a package it won't let you re-publish it until 24hs have passed.*

You can unpublish the package leaving that version blank (but please understand the implications before you do this): `npm unpublish [@<scope>/]<name>[@<version>]`

Note: The `--force` argument is deprecated.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the npm documentation for [unpublish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/unpublish) states that "Even if a package version is unpublished, that specific name and version combination can never be reused. In order to publish the package again, a new version number must be used.". This essentially means that unpublishing and republishing is not a work-around in updating documentation without a patch bump.

Comment: Be careful when doing this, after you unpublish a package it won't let you re-publish it until 24hs have passed.

Answer (score 2):

For others who land here and think they did it right. Yes, you did it right; Check your `npm` page in 5-10 minutes.